# Como adicionar links de redirecionamento em elementos da playlist do Jwplayer

Tags: javascript, html, reprodutor-de-video

Ola gostaria da ajuda de vocês para poder dar finalização o código do Jwplayer que eu estou fazendo. Como eu ainda sou iniciante tem muita coisa que não sei fazer ate o presente momento, por isso espero poder conta com a ajuda de vocês.

O meu problema e o seguinte, eu gostaria de saber se e possível adicionar nos vídeos contidos dentro da playlist do Jwplayer links de redirecionamento imediato.

De forma que quando o usuário clicar na imagem do vídeo, em vez do vídeo ser aberto no player, ele seja redirecionado para uma pagina especifica, de acordo com o link contido dentro do elemento em questão. No código abaixo possui 7 vídeos na playlist, e gostaria de poder colocar 6 links diferentes. Para efetuar o que eu expliquei.

Mantendo em funcionamento a penas o primeiro vídeo, e executar esse procedimento somente nos 6 vídeos contidos na galeria que estão apois o primeiro vídeo que esta na primeira posição.

Eu fiquei sabendo que da para fazer esse tipo de procedimento utilizando javascript. Mais como eu mencionei ainda sou iniciante.

Meu codigo do Jwplayer

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
                <script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/As3vnHJG.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        var JWp = {

            'flashplayer': '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jwplayer/5.10/player.swf',
            'skin-name': 'seven',
            'skinactive': '#0099ff',
            'skininactive': '#f9f9f9',
            'skinbackground': '#000000',
            'logofile': '',
            'logoposition': 'top-right',
        };
        /* ]]> */
        </script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
    </head>
    <body data-rsssl=1>
        <div id="video"></div>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            var playerInstance = jwplayer("video");
            playerInstance.setup({
                playlist: [{
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '1'
},
{
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '2',
}, {
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '3',
}, {
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '4',
}, {
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '5',
}, {
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '6',
}, {
  file: 'video url',
  image: 'imagem',
  title: 'titulo',
  mediaid: '7',
}, ],
                mute: "false",
                autostart: "false",
                repeat: "false",
                abouttext: JWp.abouttext,
                aboutlink: JWp.aboutlink,
                height: "100%",
                width: "100%",
                stretching: "uniform",
                primary: "html5",
                flashplayer: JWp.flashplayer,
                preload:"metadata",
                skin: {
                    name:JWp.skinname,
                    active:JWp.skinactive,
                    inactive:JWp.skininactive,
                    background: JWp.skinbackground
                },
                logo: {
                    file:JWp.logofile,
                    hide:"false",
                    link:JWp.logolink,
                    margin:"15",
                    position:JWp.logoposition
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar os [eventos](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/search.html?q=event) pera pegar os atributo no seu json playlist.

```js
jwplayer("player").setup({

  playlist: [{
    "file": "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/RDn7eg0o-cIp6U8lV.mp4",
    "image": "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/RDn7eg0o-720.jpg",
    "title": "Surfing Ocean Wave",
    "site": "www.yahoo.com"
  }, {
    "file": "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/tkM1zvBq-cIp6U8lV.mp4",
    "image": "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/tkM1zvBq-720.jpg",
    "title": "Surfers at Sunrise",
    "site": "www.bing.com"
  }, {
    "file": "//content.jwplatform.com/videos/i3q4gcBi-cIp6U8lV.mp4",
    "image": "//content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/i3q4gcBi-720.jpg",
    "title": "Road Cycling Outdoors",
    "site": "www.google.com"
  }]

});

jwplayer('player').onPlay(function(event) {

  index = jwplayer('player').getPlaylistIndex();
  item = jwplayer('player').getPlaylistItem(index);
  window.location.href = item.site
});
```

```html
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/As3vnHJG.js"></script>
<div id="player"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta, mais eu ainda não entendi como posso mudar do evento alerta para o modo de redirecionamento.

Comment: Olá @Ani eu editei a resposta e inseri o redirecionamento para uma outra página (window.location.href = item.site). Coloquei o alert para ilustrar como você poderia pegar o link contido na sua playlist. Caso resolva seu problema, favor marcar como resposta para poder ajudar outras pessoas com seu mesmo problema. Att.

Comment: Esta funciona perfeitamente, mais mencionei um ponto incorreto, o player deve ter no máximo o primeiro vídeo funcionando, depois que clicar na listagem, no modo playlist só redirecione, se o item da galeria for clicado. Seria possível você passar essa correção, me desculpe antecipadamente. Editei a pergunta para ficar em conformidade, com a resposta.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso:  if(index >  0){
    window.location.href = item.site
}

Comment: Obrigada agora tudo esta funcionando perfeitamente. Estou com uma duvida, estou precisando dar um pequeno aprimoramento no código, eu tenho que abrir um novo tópico de pergunta ?

Comment: Eu que agradeço em poder te ajudar. Sim, crie outro tópico e inclua seu código. Assim outras pessoas também poderão te ajudar. Caso tenha dúvidas a respeito de como funciona o stack veja a central de ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help. Att.